# Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen "nun" und "jetzt"?

Tags: translation, word-usage, meaning, word-choice, difference

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[What is the difference between "nun" and "jetzt"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24295/what-is-the-difference-between-nun-and-jetzt)*

Ich übersetzte die beiden als "now", aber ich vermute, dass es irgendeinen Unterschied in ihrer Bedeutung geben muss. Welcher?

Comment: Warum vermutest du das?

Comment: Ich vermute es, weil es ich nehme es an und halte es für möglich.                                           ver·mu·ten <vermutest, vermutete, hat vermutet> (mit OBJ)
1. jmd. vermutet etwas glauben, annehmen, für möglich halten.

Comment: Wir wissen, was *vermuten* heißt, aber das bedeutet auch, dass du einen Grund zu der Vermutung haben musst. Das ist, was Raphael wissen wollte.

Comment: Ich danke dir für deine Erklärung für das, was Raphael meint. Vielleicht er auch, vielleicht die ganze Welt. Ich freue mich über das hohe Niveau dieses Gespräches, so hoch, dass man sogar über den Grund befragt wird, warum man ein bestimmtes Wort benutzt. Als gewöhnlicher Mensch, die Gründe für das, was ich sage oder tue sind so vielfältig wie mir unbekannt. So, wenn das Wort “vermuten” nicht die richtige ist oder jemanden stört, bitte ich sie auf Knien um Entschuldigung.

Comment: Ich denke, dass das Verb *vermuten* richtig da ist. Nur fragen die Leuten hier, *warum* du das vermutet hast. Tatsächich kann das allen helfen, eine bessere Antwort zu liefern.

Comment: @Calogero why so hostile?

Answer (score 18):

(Note: For an English answer see [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24295/what-is-the-difference-between-nun-and-jetzt).)

Der Unterschied ist nicht sehr groß, wenn es überhaupt einen gibt. *Jetzt* wird möglicherweise öfter in der gesprochenen Sprache verwendet, *nun* in der geschriebenen, aber auch hier gibt es vielleicht regionale Unterschiede.

Wenn man denn unbedingt unterscheiden möchte: *jetzt* heißt "in diesem Moment, genau jetzt, sofort, unverzüglich", während "nun" mehr die Bedeutung von "in der Gegenwart, bis hierhin" hat, es schließt an Vorangeganges an bzw. denkt bisher Geschehenes mit. Der Ausdruck ist etwas weiter und wird bisweilen auch poetisch oder als Füllwort gebraucht:

> Nun da alle Königssöhne in die Ferne gezogen waren, blieb nur noch ... 
>   Nun, das kommt darauf an ...

Daneben gibt es noch eine Reihe von Idiomen bei denen *nun* nicht durch *jetzt* (oder umgekehrt) ersetzt werden kann:

> Nicht jetzt! Nun denn. Jetzt oder nie. Wann, wenn nicht jetzt? ... im Hier und Jetzt.

Wenn man über den gegenwärtigen Zustand einer Sache spricht muss man ebenfalls *jetzt* benutzen:

> Die ehemalige "Gebrüder Heindl Gmbh" (jetzt: Heindl & Co. KG) ...

In der Regel sind *nun* und *jetzt* aber Synonyme.

Comment: Thank you! i was always confused from nun. Now I know. ^^

Comment: Answer translated into German by popular request. English original preserved, see link on top.

Answer (score 9):

Ich beschränke mich in der Antwort auf die Wortbedeutungen von `jetzt` und `nun`, die sich mit `now` übersetzen ließen.

## Ergebnis

`nun` bezieht sich auf Prozesse und Handlungen, `jetzt` auf den Zustand der Gegenwart.

Zur Erläuterung verwende ich Beispiele aus den Wiktionary-Einträgen: [jetzt](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jetzt), [nun](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nun)

## nun

> Was wird *nun* geschehen?

`nun` bezeichnet hier die Gegenwart als Beginn eines zukünftigen Prozesses.

> Das ist nun geschehen.

`nun` bezeichnet hier die Gegenwart als Abschluss eines vergangenen Prozesses.

> Was haben wir nun? (Im Gegensatz zu gerade eben im Gegensatz zu gleich.)

`nun` bezeichnet hier die Gegenwart als Schritt in einem Prozess, der von der Vergangenheit in die Zukunft führt.

> Nun ziehen wir die Schraube fest.

`nun` bezeichnet hier den aktuellen Schritt als Folge des vorhergehenden Schrittes.

> Nun, was ist deine Entscheidung? Nun, es ist wahr.

`nun` bezeichnet hier die Gegenwart oder aktuelle Situation als einen Teil eines größeren Prozesses oder Sachzusammenhangs.

## Jetzt

> Ich habe jetzt keine Zeit.

Es geht um keinen Prozess oder ein größeres Ganzes, sondern lediglich um den jetzigen Zustand.

> Ich denke jetzt anders darüber, als ich es früher gemacht habe.

`jetzt` bezeichnet die Gegenwart, die nach einem früheren Zeitpunkt liegt. Es geht hier nicht um den Prozess, der zum Denkwandel geführt hat.

> Jetzt können wir noch Hühnchen essen, ohne mit Chlor vergiftet zu werden.

`jetzt` bezeichnet die Gegenwart, die vor einem zukünftigen Zeitpunkt liegt. Es geht hier nicht um den Prozess, der zur Chlorvergiftung führt.

## Zusammenfassung

Beide Wörter bezeichnen die Gegenwart und grenzen sie von Vergangenheit und Zukunft ab.

`jetzt` beschränkt sich dabei aber auf die zeitliche Ordnung Vergangenheitjetzt für beliebige Zeitdauern von `in diesen Moment` bis `heutzutage`.

`nun` hingegen bezeichnet genau die Relation der drei Zeiten. Wie kommt es von der Vergangenheit zur Gegenwart? Wie kommt es von der Gegenwart zur Zukunft? Wie hängt die Gegenwart zeitlich aber auch inhaltlich prozedural mit Gegenwart und Zukunft zusammen? In diesem Sinn funktioniert `nun` nur für für den Prozess typische Zeitdauern (beim Backen Minuten und Stunden, in politischen Prozessen Jahre, in kosmologischen Zeitdauern auch Jahrmillionen).

Answer (score 2):

Oft kann man beide mit "now" übersetzen, oder zumindest mit einer Konstruktion, die now enthält. Hier einige Beispiele, wo man sich schon zwingen müsste, zu einer Übersetzung mit "now" zu greifen:

> Nun ja, man könnte das auch so sehen...
>
> Hast du dich nun entschieden?
>
> Nichts, das ist nun einmal so.
>
> Echt jetzt?

(Das letzte Beispiel ist möglicherweise eines von wenigen, wo man "jetzt" nicht mit "now" übersetzen kann. Bei "nun" geht das viel öfter nicht.)

Im Deutschen unterscheiden sich die zwei insofern, als dass man "nun" vielseitiger (anschließend, entgegenstellend, einleitend usw.) verwenden kann.

"Jetzt" hingegen bezeichnet fast immer "einen mehr oder weniger eng begrenzten Zeitraum in der Gegenwart" (Duden). Und in den Fällen, wo es das nicht tut, kann es mit "nun" übersetzt werden.

Answer (score 0):

Beide Wörter sind in der Bedeutung fast gleich, aber sie sind nicht einfach austauschbar.

Beispiel: Man sagt nicht "Der Wald ist voll von Bäumen." Das ist eher eine Stilblüte. Ein Wald besteht "nun mal" aus Bäumen. - Hier kann man nicht 
"jetzt mal" sagen.

Den unterschiedlichen Gebrauch von "nun" und "jetzt" kann man nicht mit Definitionen fassen oder mit einer einfachen Regel für Anfänger klar machen, vieles ist einfach idiomatisch.

Der unterschiedliche Gebrauch ließe sich nur mit einer größeren Anzahl von kommentierten Beispielen zeigen.

Answer (score -3):

nun – now

jetzt – now

http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/jetzt it's a direct synonym.

Was machst du nun? Du hast drei Tage drüber nachgedacht.

Was machst du jetzt? Du hast drei Tage drüber nachgedacht.

I think nun is more informal.

> Saying: Und was machen Sie nun?

Sounds a bit rude and demanding to me.

> Saying: Und was machen Sie jetzt?

Sounds a bit less rude to me.