# What is the difference between "nun" and "jetzt"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen "nun" und "jetzt"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12126/wo-liegt-der-unterschied-zwischen-nun-und-jetzt)*

I hear *nun* and *jetzt* used a lot but I've not been able to pick out what the difference is between them.

Could anyone give some clarification on any differences between the two please?

Comment: **To close voters:** http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei

Comment: Copied & pasted. I'll translate the other answer into German as time permits.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

(Hinweis: Für eine deutsche Antwort, siehe [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12126/wo-liegt-der-unterschied-zwischen-nun-und-jetzt).)

I don't think there is much of a difference. Perhaps *jetzt* is more often used in spoken language, while *nun* is more often written than spoken, although there may well be regional differences.

If you must make a difference: *jetzt* means "right now, this instant" where the meaning of *nun* is closer to "presently" or "by now". It's somewhat broader and can be used as a filler as well (in a fairy tale, say):

> Nun da alle Königssöhne in die Ferne gezogen waren, blieb nur noch ... (Now that all of the king's sons had wandered off, only ... remained ...)

*Jetzt* can never mean "well", not even colloquially, whereas "nun" is often used as an interjection:

> Nun, das kommt darauf an ... (Well, that depends ...)

There are also some fixed expressions where you can't really exchange one for the other:

> Nicht jetzt! Nun denn. Jetzt oder nie. Wann, wenn nicht jetzt? ... im Hier und Jetzt.

For the most part *nun* and *jetzt* are synomyns, though. There's another thing: if you are talking about the current state of something, use *jetzt*:

> Die ehemalige "Gebrüder Heindl Gmbh" (jetzt: Heindl & Co. KG) ...

Answer (score 4):

Jetzt: now.
Nun: currently, presently, (and it means also) actually.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your answer to add some explanations, e.g., in what context you can use one and not the other?